# How can we dis-connect all the active users on sql-server 2005 express using sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can we dis-connect all the active users on sql-server 2005 express using sql

Comment: i need to do this for restoring the backup of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fire this sql query:

```
USE [master] 
GO

 ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; RESTORE DATABASE MyDB FROM DISK = 'backupfile path' WITH REPLACE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [YourDB] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

Your Restore Statement

ALTER DATABASE [YourDB] SET  MULTI_USER
GO
```